# Procedural textures not showing in Material view

Tags: texturing, materials, 3d-view

I have a very simple node setup as shown below in cycles.
Rendering is not a problem but I would like to preview the material in Material View. 
Does anyone know if this is possible, or not?

[image: Node Setup]

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Same opinion. Use the real time render in viewport (Shift+Z) to see it

Comment: I need this for live VJ ing. Viewport render is not an option since render time is not synchronous with expected fps. It's also very pixelated and lq as you know for live animation preview.

Comment: baking the texture is the only way to do this currently.  Someone would have to build GLSL versions of the textures for them to be seen in the viewport.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, this is not possible at the moment.

I do find myself quite often wishing this was possible, but I am afraid it is not.  the closest thing is, as [Bithur said in the comments](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24721/procedural-textures-not-showing-in-material-view#comment36783_24721), you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to activate rendered viewport mode.

I have heard that the devs are working on adding this support, I have no idea when it is projected to come out though.

Comment: In 2.78 procedural textures are still not visible in the *Texture* view, but they are visible in the *Material* view.